# How to write valid context in a customized adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter

I am using a customized adapter for passing data to/from Sq-lite . I need to pass reference of the  fragment in the following method of  adapter class . How can that be achieved?
** What is to be written instead of  "FragmentGroups.getActivity() " ?

```
public void Set_Referash_Data() {
            data.clear();
            db = new SendJobDataBase(new FragmentGroups.getActivity());
            ArrayList<member> contact_array_from_db = db.Get_Contacts();

            for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

                int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
                String name = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
            //    String mobile = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getPhoneNumber();
            //    String email = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getEmail();
                member cnt = new member();
                cnt.setID(tidno);
                cnt.setName(name);
            //    cnt.setEmail(email);
            //    cnt.setPhoneNumber(mobile);

                data.add(cnt);
            }
            db.close();
            gdb = new GroupAdapter(FragmentGroups.getActivity(), R.layout.listrow_item,
                data);
            l1.setAdapter(gdb);
            gdb.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

GroupAdapter.java :

```
 package com.sunmobile.navigationdrawer;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

      public class GroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<member> {


        GroupAdapter gdb;
        Activity activity;
        int layoutResourceId;
        member user;
        ArrayList<member> data = new ArrayList<member>();
        ListView l1;
        SendJobDataBase db;

     public GroupAdapter(Activity act, int layoutResourceId,
                ArrayList<member> data) {
                super(act, layoutResourceId, data);
                this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
                this.activity = act;
                this.data = data;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            MemberHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new MemberHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_name_txt);
            holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            row.setTag(holder);
           } else {
        holder = (MemberHolder) row.getTag();
            }
           user = data.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(user.getName());
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                adb.setTitle("Delete?");
                adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ");
                final int user_id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                adb.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                        // MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
                        SendJobDataBase dBHandler = new SendJobDataBase(
                            activity.getApplicationContext());
                       dBHandler.Delete_Contact(user_id);
                       GroupAdapter.this.onResume();

                    }
                    });    


                adb.show();
            }

            });   
            return row;

        }


      public void Set_Referash_Data() {
                data.clear();
                db = new SendJobDataBase(FragmentGroups.this.getActivity());
                ArrayList<member> contact_array_from_db = db.Get_Contacts();

                for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

                    int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
                    String name = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
                                data.add(cnt);
                }
                db.close();
                gdb = new GroupAdapter(FragmentGroups.this.getActivity(), R.layout.listrow_item, data);
                l1.setAdapter(gdb);
                gdb.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

        class MemberHolder {
            TextView name;
            Button delete;
        }

        }
```

FragmentGroups:

```
package com.sunmobile.navigationdrawer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.PasswordDB;
import com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.R;

public class FragmentGroups extends Fragment {

     SendJobDataBase db; 
     Cursor cursor;
     ArrayList<member> membr,membr2;
     ListView list1 ;
     ListView list2 ;
     Button group1;
     Button group2;
     GroupAdapter groupadapter;


    public FragmentGroups(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_fragment, container, false);

        group1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Gp1);
        group2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Gp2);


    list1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list1);

     this.db = new SendJobDataBase(getActivity());
    membr=db.getMembersList();  

        groupadapter= new GroupAdapter(this.getActivity(),R.layout.listrow_item ,membr);
        list1.setAdapter( groupadapter);     




   list2 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list2);
   membr2=db.getMembersList2(); 
    groupadapter= new GroupAdapter(this.getActivity(),R.layout.listrow_item ,membr2);
    list2.setAdapter( groupadapter);     



      group1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

        list1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        list2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
});


group2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        list1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        list2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
return rootView;

    }       

}
```

Comment: Is `FragmentGroups` a `Fragment`?

Comment: Where is Set_Referash_Data() executed ?

Comment: So what is wrong with `FragmentGroups.getActivity()`? `getActivity()` returns the activtiy this fragment is associated with. post `GroupAdapter`

Comment: " Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getActivity() from the type Fragment "

Comment: @user3467204 use `FragmentGroups.this.getActivity()`

Comment: @user3467204 Your title is wrong. You want a valid context in adapter not reference to fragment. Edit and change your question title

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks but now it is showing as " No enclosing instance of the type FragmentGroups is accessible in scope "

Comment: @user3467204 post your full code.

Comment: @user3467204 `Set_Referash_Data()` is inside adapter class??

Comment: yes, Set_Referash_Data() is inside the GroupAdapter class .

Comment: @user3467204 that is not necessary. You populate list in fragment itself and pass the same to the adapter constructor.

Comment: @user3467204 i don't understand the need for 2 ArrayList??

Comment: I am having 2 buttons and on their click two list (one at a time ) will be shown . I need to pass different data to the list . So, is that a wrong approach . Is it possible to use the same list. Both will have unequal number of elements and they are to be manipulated in different ways.

Comment: @user3467204 this is a messy approach. any way its left to you to decide. However move the method to the fragment

Comment: would you like to recommend any other approach. I also agree that this is very confusing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form your comment

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getActivity()
>   from the type Fragment

Use

```
FragmentGroups.this.getActivity()
```

instead of

```
FragmentGroups.getActivity()
```

Edit:

Move the below to `FragmentGroups` class

```
  public void Set_Referash_Data() {
            data.clear();
            db = new SendJobDataBase(FragmentGroups.this.getActivity());
            ArrayList<member> contact_array_from_db = db.Get_Contacts();

            for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

                int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
                String name = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
                            data.add(cnt);
            }
            db.close();
            gdb = new GroupAdapter(FragmentGroups.this.getActivity(), R.layout.listrow_item, data);
            l1.setAdapter(gdb);
            gdb.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

And call `Set_Referash_Data` when you want in your fragment.